# LINQ Contains vs Intersect (vs anything else!)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable

I have a large IEnumerable of EntityObjects and a large IEnumerable of strings, which are a key of the objects.

I want to obtain a new list of only the objects where the key is matched.  At the moment I am doing this through `Contains()` - but it seems pretty slow?

```
class Foo {
  string Key
  string Prop1
  int Prop2
  decimal Prop3
  Bar Prop4
  Thing Prop5
  Stuff Prop6
  ...more properties
}

IEnumerable<Foo> foos
IEnumerable<string> fooKeys

var matchedFoos = foos.Where(f => fooKeys.Contains(f.Key));
```

This works and returns what I expect, but seems to be slow and I think there must be a better way?  I've seen a few posts on Intersect, but seems to be for enumerables of the same type?

For info:

- `foos.Count()` approx 164,000
- `fooKeys.Count()` approx 75,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should probably do the search on database (using LINQ to Entities), not on application (using LINQ to Objects).
2. You can change `fooKeys` to `HashSet<string>` (if it's not one already) to make `Contains()` method call *O(1)* instead of *O(n)*:

   ```
   var keesSet = new HashSet<string>(fooKeys);
   var matchedFoos = foos.Where(f => keesSet.Contains(f.Key));
   ```

   But with collections that big it will still require a fair amount of time to perform the search.

Comment: "list" of foos is not materialised at this stage, so was hoping (perhaps incorrectly) that the Contains() would be doing the query of the db.  Will make the keys a hashset and test...

Comment: To make database query `foos` has to be `IQueryable<Entity>`, not `IEnumerable<Entity>`. Using `Contains` will then generate proper `IN ()` statement within SQL query.

Comment: Will make sure it's IQueryable - will HashSet still be better for the Contains()?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you're using `IQueryable`. `IEnumerable<string>` is fine then.

Answer (score 3):

I think yet another variant with [join clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb311040.aspx) like this

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos
IEnumerable<string> fooKeys

var matchedFoos = from foo in foos
                  join fk in fooKeys on foo.Key equals fk
                  select foo;
```